# how to succesfully boot into bootloader/fastboot mode on alcatel 5049z smartphone

Tags: adb, usb, fastboot, bootloader

I am having issues( i am a "novice" when it comes to unlocking a30 android bootloader with a PC...) with booting into bootloader/fastboot mode on my stock rom--android 7--Alcatel a30(non rooted 5049z?)smartphone;i have tried the power button/volume button sequence method...no luck there,and have tried the adb method using:adb reboot bootloader/fastboot..again no luck!!!

I would like to know if any forum members know how i may unlock my a30 bootloader without(if possible?)rebooting to the aforementioned bootloader modes or is this phones bootloader unlockable without removing FRP(Factory Reset Protection)????

Thanks in advance for any helpful replies!

Comment: Not all devices have a user-accessible fastboot mode, and considering that yours is a MediaTek-powered device, it gets even less likely. Not to mention that many modern phones require flipping a switch in Developer Options to enable unlocking.

Comment: @AndyYan and even if fastboot mode is accessible, one may need an unlock code from the OEM to unlock bootloader. And there's is a possibility that vendors provide no mechanism to unlock bootloader like most of the phones sold by network carriers are not unlockable. Sometimes hacks/exploits work for unlocking/rooting but most of the times you are out of luck with such phones.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Are you stuck with FRP and don't know the Google account credentials and hoping that flashing ROM using fastboot or flashing a custom recovery would help you out? Booting into fastboot mode is an intermediate step, not the end goal.

Answer (score 3):

You have several questions,
To answer the last one,  yes... and no

On device's that use MTK CPU's, you don't need to unlock the bootloader as the bootloader on MTK's is not Fastboot .   .MTK is famous for being UNBRICKABLE !!! Meaning you don't need to unlock the Fastboot at all...

The reason your having trouble is because it isn't necessary to unlock the bootloader ...

I'm not sure why Andy### thinks that being a MediaTek would make it harder, because that's just not the case... it usually means easier...

Let me explain why the Fastboot is useless..

On MediTek Device's, you dont flash new images via Fastboot because there is size limitations to each image, if you tried to flash a massive 3 GB system, it wouldn't allow you to, because of maximum flash size in Fastboot....   Instead MediaTek uses a Pre-Boot that is prior to the bootloader, it doesn't even have a GUI... This is called the Preloader on MTK Devices, and you do all your flashing using the Preloader... Usually you use a tool called SP Flash Tool for doing flashes....

Unlocking your bootloader isn't necessary, and disabling FRP is not going to make any changes to your bootloader unlocking... You flash a recovery image via the Preloader in SP Flash Tool, and then wipe the partition called FRP, and factory reset... it isn't like other Android ( HTC for example ) Htc devices need to be unlocked in order to install custom recoveries etc... this is not even a problem with MTK Device's because the Preloader gives you factory level flashing abilities.